# Django: Counting the number of objects changed in a migration

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a Django app. I'd like to add a decorator around each of my migrations that will count the number of objects that were changed by my migration.

So basically, disregarding migrations right now, I need a way to tell Django: "Starting at this point, please count the number of ORM objects that had any fields modified" and then at the end, get a count of these objects.

Is that possible with Django?

Comment: It _might_ be possible to do what you want to do: you might need to inspect some stuff around ProjectState and see what has changed. I'm not sure exactly what syntax you are wanting to use though: could you show us what you think it might look like when done?